# Cython not faster than Python

Tags: python, web, cython

I'm testing the performance of Python vs Cython for web scraping using while loop. Sadly I don't se any improvement.

Here is my Python code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time
from multiprocessing import cpu_count, pool


def funct():
    i=0
    url = 'https://www.tocnaura.si/' 
    tic = time.perf_counter()
    s = requests.session()


    while i<=100:
        result = s.get(url)
        doc = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "html.parser")
        tag = doc.find('script').string
        string = tag[29:48].replace(',', ':')
        print(string, flush=True)
        i+=1

    toc = time.perf_counter()
    print(f'End in {toc - tic:0.4f} sec', flush=True)
```

And here is my Cython code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time
from multiprocessing import cpu_count, pool

cdef int i
cdef str url, doc, tag, string, s, result
cdef float tic, toc


def funct():
    i=0
    url = 'https://www.tocnaura.si/'
    tic = time.perf_counter()
    s = requests.session()


    while i<=100:
        result = s.get(url)
        doc = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "html.parser")
        tag = doc.find('script').string
        string = tag[29:48].replace(',', ':')
        print(string)
        i+=1

    toc = time.perf_counter()
    print(f'End in {toc - tic:0.4f} sec')
```

Now I use the script for test the Python and Cython code:

```
import Time1
import Time2
import time


start1 = time.time()
Time1.funct()
stop1 = time.time()
print(stop1 - start1)

start2 = time.time()
Time2.funct()
stop2 = time.time()
print(stop2 - start2)
```

And my output is:

```
15,58 sec for Cyton
15,54 sec for Python
```

What am I doing wrong here?

I was expecting about 100x times better performance using Cython

Comment: Looks like this program is mostly IO-bound, and Cython doesn't make IO faster.

Comment: Right.  Even if you optimized the code so that it took 0 time, you would still be waiting for the network transfers.

Comment: Even if not IO bound, all the work is in BeautifulSoup (which Cython doesn't change)

Comment: `result = s.get(url)`: please **don't do that**! You are saturating the server with 100 requests while only one is actually needed! Please put `result = s.get(url)` outside the loop. In fact, the loop does 100 times the same thing so it is not even needed... Even if this is an unrealistic example and you need to scan many pages, then you need not to reopen new connections which are expensive. Note that doing many request like this can be detected as a DDOS attack and you can be banned from the server temporary (or even permanently if you the number of request is significantly bigger).